# make not saving output of a command inside a rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project which I have to run multiple randomly generated strings to it of different lengths to get its complexity experimentally.

I have done a script to generate those sequences and placed them all inside a folder. They all have suffix ".in". I am trying to generate a makefile inside this folder which calls:

```
{ time ../proj1 < gen.in 1> /dev/null 2>&1; } 2> gen.time
```

for each generated file.
So far I have tried something like this:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory # No entering and leaving messages

all:: clean # run tests
    @$(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) `ls *.in | sed -e "s/in/time/"`

%.time: %.in
    { time ../proj1 < $< 2> /dev/null 2>&1; } 2> $@

clean::
    rm -f *.time
```

The makefile starts executing, but instead of giving the right results, it creates empty files. If I try to execute the commands that the make prints onto the terminal, they work as intended... I can't wrap my head around about what am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example command line:

```
{ time ../proj1 < gen.in 1> /dev/null 2>&1; } 2> gen.time
```

In your makefile:

```
{ time ../proj1 < $< 2> /dev/null 2>&1; } 2> $@
```

Note `1>` vs. `2>` so that's clearly wrong: if you'd shown us the output of your run we'd be able to see the output.  But that's not what's causing your files to be empty.

The reason is that when you run this command in your shell it's using your shell, which is likely `bash`, and `bash` has a built-in version of `time`.  But when you run make, it's using the value of the make `SHELL` variable which is always `/bin/sh` by default: on many systems that's not bash it's a fast POSIX-compliant shell like dash, which doesn't have a built-in version of `time`, so you're running `/usr/bin/time` instead: that version just writes to stderr like any other program:

```
$ /usr/bin/time sleep 2 2>/dev/null
$
```

You need to either rewrite your rule, or add:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

to your makefile to force it to use bash (of course then it won't work on any system that doesn't have bash installed).